# Basic proof verification of biconditional formula

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, first-order-logic

Let $\alpha \in X$. I want to prove following statement
$$
\text{Condition  } A(\alpha) \text{ is satisfied} \iff \text{Condition  } B \text{ is satisfied}.
$$

First I assume that  $\alpha \in X$ and Condition $B$ is satisfied then I show that Condition $A(\alpha)$ satisfied.

For other direction I assume that $\alpha \in X$ and $A(\alpha)$ is satisfied. Since $A(\alpha)$ is satisfied for arbitrary $\alpha$. It is also satisfied by a concrete $\alpha$.  I make some deductions for this concrete alpha and finally reach the conclusion that condition B is satisfied.

Now, have I proven the above proposition correctly?

Comment: This is really unclear - your notation makes it seem that B doesn't depend on alpha, but then you talk about B being satisfied for a "concrete" alpha. It would be better to include the details of the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: @MatthewTowers I make some deductions for this concrete alpha and finally reach the conclusion that condition B is satisfied. As you said, condition B is not depend on alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct.

Generally speaking, for any two well-formed formulas $P,Q$, the [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) formula $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is logicallally equivantent to the formula $(P \to Q) \wedge (Q \to P)$, and if you can show both $P \to Q$ and $Q \to P$ on two separate lines of proof, then you can infer $(P \to Q) \wedge (Q \to P)$ by [conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction).

Given $\alpha \in X$... by first assuming $B$ and then deducing $A(\alpha)$, you derive the conditional formula $B \to A(\alpha)$ by [conditional proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) (also known as arrow introduction). Likewise, by deducing $B$ under the assumption of $A(\alpha)$, you derive the conditional formula $A(\alpha) \to B$. After having derived both $A(\alpha) \to B$ and $B \to A(\alpha)$ on two separate lines of proof, you may infer $[ A(\alpha) \to B) \wedge (B \to A(\alpha)]$ by conjunction introduciton and conclude $A(\alpha) \leftrightarrow B$ by definition of biconditional.

Comment: Someone said to me for this proof "the claim is made for all $\alpha\in X$, but the proof is given for concrete $\alpha$. This is no proof." This is what confused me.

Comment: if your choice of $\alpha$ is arbitrary, then your proof will be generalizable to all elements of $X$. In other words, when you select an element $\alpha$ from $X$ and as you attempt to prove something about $\alpha$, do not utilize or attribute any property to $\alpha$ except that which is common to all elements of $X$. I could probably give you a better response if I saw your specific proof.

Comment: You Claim to be using first order logic but I don't actually see any quantifiers in your formula